# Error: symbol 'xxx' is multiply defined

Tags: ios, linker, metal

I added multiple Metal shaders to my code and I now get:

```
Error: symbol '<shader name>' is multiply defined
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/usr/bin/metallib failed with exit code 1
```

I don't include `.metal` files anywhere (XCode takes care of the compilation itself) and I cannot add `inline` or `static` to the function, so what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently if a shader function has *exactly* the same signature as another one in another file, it's seen as duplicate. I changed the name of the struct used for output and it linked.

Answer (score 3):

There are also problems defining functions in a header file. I thought I could inline them, but it seems I can only declare them.

For instance, I had this header file,

```
// ShaderMath.h
#pragma once
using namespace metal;
float4 conjugate(const float4 q);

float4 conjugate(const float4 q) {
  return float4( -q.xyz, q.w );
}
```

If I include this header in more than one metal file, I get the "multiply defined" error. However, if I move the definition to a .metal file, then it works. The header file is just,

```
// ShaderMath.h
#pragma once
using namespace metal;
float4 conjugate(const float4 q);
```

and the metal file,

```
// ShaderMath.metal
#include <metal_stdlib>
#include "ShaderMath.h"
using namespace metal;
float4 conjugate(const float4 q) {
  return float4( -q.xyz, q.w );
}
```

I hope this helps other people stuck with this same problem.

Comment: Same case for me, that's an ugly design from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

for me, this happens when i rename metal files.  for some reason, there's some artifact that hangs around and i start seeing the duplicate symbols error on build.  not sure if this is a bug or what, but the only way i can fix it is to rename the function.

Comment: You should also be able to fix this by cleaning the project with Cmd+Shift+K.